# yarn create not working like npx

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg, npx

I have a script that does this

```
npx create-react-app --scripts-version /tmp/tmp.V987BAD2Te/react-scripts.tgz /tmp/tmp.V987BAD2Te/test-app
```

Its breaking in Windows with message "Path must be a string. Received undefined".
I do not want to upgrade npm for now and so replaced this with

```
yarn create react-app --scripts-version /tmp/tmp.V987BAD2Te/react-scripts.tgz /tmp/tmp.V987BAD2Te/test-app
```

But it does not install react-scripts from the temp path.Why

Comment: You should use tag `yarnpkg` instead of `yarn`.